# How can I add search help in a SAP Fiori Worklist Application created using CDS annotations?

Tags: annotations, abap, sap-fiori, cds

I want to add search help to a field in a SAP Fiori Worklist Application created using CDS annotations. What annotations should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a value help view and associate it by using annotation `@Consumption.valueHelp:`

```
define view C_A_VIEW as select from I_A_VIEW as A      
  association [0..1] to I_VALUEHELP_VIEW as _VALUEHLEP
    on $projection.....
{ 

    @Consumption.valueHelp: '_VALUEHLEP'
    A.Field  

}
```

It is documented in here https://help.sap.com/viewer/cc0c305d2fab47bd808adcad3ca7ee9d/7.5.9/en-US/8a8415c033d441b2b079a53aff129463.html